# How to convert an deprecated SoapService call to the new UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I found an example on how to call a webservice with Google drive scripts here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/soap_geoip_example

```
function determineCountryFromIP(ipAddress) {
    var wsdl = SoapService.wsdl("http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?wsdl");
    var geoService = wsdl.getGeoIPService();

    var param = Xml.element("GetGeoIP", [
              Xml.attribute("xmlns", "http://www.webservicex.net/"),
              Xml.element("IPAddress", [
                ipAddress
              ])
            ]);

    var result = geoService.GetGeoIP(param);
    return result.Envelope.Body.GetGeoIPResponse.GetGeoIPResult.CountryCode.Text;
}
```

However this uses the SoapService which is deprecated. the documentation says I should use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
Converting the input xml is easy. But can anyone tell me how to call a webservice with the UrlFetchApp?

Comment: Tag this question with `google-apps-script` instead of `google-drive-sdk`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out to be a lot more work, but after a day of googling and trying i got it to work with the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

```
function UrlFetchAppDetermineCountryFromIP_(ipAddress) {
  var xml =          
     "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    +"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">"
      +"<SOAP-ENV:Body>"
        +"<GetGeoIP xmlns=\"http://www.webservicex.net/\">"
          +"<IPAddress>"+ ipAddress +"</IPAddress>"
        +"</GetGeoIP>"
      +"</SOAP-ENV:Body>"
    +"</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"

  var options =
  {
    "method" : "post",
    "contentType" : "text/xml",
    "payload" : xml
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?wsdl", options);

  var xmlResult = XmlService.parse(result).getRootElement();
  var soapNamespace = xmlResult.getNamespace("soap");
  var getGeoIPResponse = xmlResult.getChild("Body", soapNamespace).getChildren()[0];
  var getGeoIPResponseNamespace = getGeoIPResponse.getNamespace();

  return getGeoIPResponse
    .getChild("GetGeoIPResult", getGeoIPResponseNamespace)
    .getChild("CountryCode", getGeoIPResponseNamespace)
    .getText();
}
```

It should probely be posable to build the payload xml with the [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/), however i tryed that for a few hours and was unable to put the 4 xmlns attributes on the Evnelope element, wich caused the webservice request to fail

Comment: I am getting a 400 response from the server ... since its google, i do not know how the request is actually made, if i use getRequest, the request looks fine. Any help ?

Comment: I just tried it again today and the above code still works, if you receive 400   (bad request), it can be because your xml is not correctly build, think about escaping double quotes and backslashes, also it can be the target server's decision to return a bad request even if the request is correct but there is something they miss or don't like

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! The first working example of how to use UrlFetchApp for web serviceses that I've found, even though I searched a bit for it!