# Accessing the Bing Ads API using Google Scripts

Tags: soap, google-apps-script, bing-api

I'm trying to access Monthly Spend amounts from a Bing Ads account using a Google Script (I'm trying to get the data into a spreadsheet). The SOAP endpoint I'm interested in is the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn451264.aspx.

My code is currently (sensitive data has been replaced):

```
function bing() {
  var wsdlURL = "https://clientcenter.api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/Billing/v9/CustomerBillingService.svc?singleWsdl";
  var wsdl = SoapService.wsdl(wsdlURL);
  var header = [
    Xml.element("ApplicationToken", [""]),
    Xml.element("AuthenticationToken", [""]),
    Xml.element("UserName", ["username"]),
    Xml.element("Password", ["password"]),
    Xml.element("DeveloperToken", ["token"])];
  var billingService = wsdl.getCustomerBillingService();
  var param = Xml.element("GetAccountMonthlySpendRequest", [
                  Xml.attribute("xmlns", "https://bingads.microsoft.com/Billing/v9"),
                  Xml.element("AccountId", [
                    "accountID"
                  ]),
                  Xml.element("MonthYear", [
                    "2014-05"
                  ])
                ]);
  Logger.log(param);
  Logger.log(header);
  var envelope = billingService.getSoapEnvelope("GetAccountMonthlySpend", param, header)
  Logger.log(envelope);
  var result = billingService.GetAccountMonthlySpend(param, header);
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

This nearly generates an envelope the same as in the doucumentation but not quite and when I  run the script I get a 500 error. Is using `SoapService` the best way to access this data? Could the above be modified to work?

Thanks!

Comment: I am looking to do the same. Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: SoapService is deprecated and the old Xml service, have been superseded by the newer XmlService. If you need to connect to a SOAP API, please use UrlFetchApp instead and construct the entire SOAP envelope manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an deprecated SoapService call to the new UrlFetchApp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899937/how-to-convert-an-deprecated-soapservice-call-to-the-new-urlfetchapp)

Comment: did you found any solution? did you used WSDL approach?

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution?