# SOAP web service call from google apps script not working

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, google-apps-script, wsdl

I am using google apps script to work with an open source platform OpenClinica and I am trying to consume their soap web service using the following code below:

```
    var xml =
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://openclinica.org/ws/studySubject/v1" xmlns:bean="http://openclinica.org/ws/beans">' +
                '<soapenv:Header>' +
                '<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">' +
                '<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-27777511" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">' +
                '<wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username>' +
                '<wsse:Password>yyy</wsse:Password>' +
                '</wsse:UsernameToken>' +
                '</wsse:Security>' +
                '</soapenv:Header>' +
                '<soapenv:Body>' +
                '<v1:importRequest>' +
                '<ODM>' +  
                '<ClinicalData StudyOID="S_PROSPER2" MetaDataVersionOID="v1.0.0">' +  
                '<SubjectData SubjectKey="SS_UU001">' +  
                '<StudyEventData StudyEventOID="SE_QUESW4" StudyEventRepeatKey="0">' +  
                '<FormData FormOID="F_RANDANDQUEST_11">' +  
                '<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG_RANDA_UNGROUPED" ItemGroupRepeatKey="1" TransactionType="Insert">' +  
                '<ItemData ItemOID="I_RANDA_RAND01" Value="1"/>' +  
                '<ItemData ItemOID="I_RANDA_RAND02" Value="1"/>' +  
                '<ItemData ItemOID="I_RANDA_RAND03" Value="1"/>' +  
                '<ItemData ItemOID="I_RANDA_RAND04" Value="1"/>' + 
                '</ItemGroupData>' +  
                '</FormData>' +  
                '</StudyEventData>' +  
                '</SubjectData>' +  
                '</ClinicalData>' +  
                '</ODM>' +  
                '</v1:importRequest>' +  
                '</soapenv:Body>' +  
                '</soapenv:Envelope>';


  var options =
      {
        "method" : "post",
        "contentType" : "text/xml",
        "payload" : xml
      };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://89.221.253.174:8080/OpenClinica-ws/ws/data/v1/dataWsdl.wsdl", options);
```

For some reason I am getting this error message:

> Request failed for
>   http://89.221.253.174:8080/OpenClinica-ws/ws/data/v1/dataWsdl.wsdl
>   returned code 404 (line 147, file "Code")

So the error is actually on this line:

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://89.221.253.174:8080/OpenClinica-ws/ws/data/v1/dataWsdl.wsdl", options);
```

If I am trying the same code from soapUI tool it works all fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://openclinica.org/ws/data/v1">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-27777511" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password>yyy</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <v1:importRequest>
          <ODM>
                <ClinicalData StudyOID="S_PROSPER2" MetaDataVersionOID="v1.0.0">
                    <SubjectData SubjectKey="SS_UU001">
                        <StudyEventData StudyEventOID="SE_QUESW4" StudyEventRepeatKey="0">
                            <FormData FormOID="F_RANDANDQUEST_11">
                                <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG_RANDA_UNGROUPED" ItemGroupRepeatKey="1" TransactionType="Insert">
                                    <ItemData ItemOID="I_RANDA_RAND01" Value="1"/>
                                    <ItemData ItemOID="I_RANDA_RAND02" Value="1"/>
                                    <ItemData ItemOID="I_RANDA_RAND03" Value="1"/>
                                    <ItemData ItemOID="I_RANDA_RAND04" Value="1"/>
                                </ItemGroupData>
                            </FormData>
                        </StudyEventData>
                    </SubjectData>
                </ClinicalData>
            </ODM>      
     </v1:importRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to add use the [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params) because you need additional parameters as demoed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899937/how-to-convert-an-deprecated-soapservice-call-to-the-new-urlfetchapp):

```
var options =
  {
    "method" : "post",
    "contentType" : "text/xml",
    "payload" : xml
  };

var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?wsdl", options);
```

Comment: I dont see any difference from what u are doing and what I was doing... Could you please state what is different your solution from what I have done? thnx