# SOAP request failing in GAS

Tags: soap, google-apps-script, soapui

When making a call to a SOAP API I get the following error:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
        a:ActionNotSupported
      </faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">
        The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
      </faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My code is in Google Apps Script, and looks something like this:

```
var apiAuthParams = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType' : 'text/xml',
  'payload' : apiAuthSoapRequest,
  'muteHttpExceptions': true
};

var apiAuthResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiAuthUrl, apiAuthParams);
```

where `apiAuthUrl` is the request URL (and I've triple checked that it's correct!) and `apiAuthSoapRequest` is the request.

If I put exactly the same request through SOAP UI to test it, with the same destination URL, it works fine, so I don't understand what is different when doing it through GAS? I regularly make SOAP calls in this manner, and have not previously encountered the issue.

Comment: Hi! Try to see if [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899937/how-to-convert-an-deprecated-soapservice-call-to-the-new-urlfetchapp) can help you.

Comment: Thanks, however this just says how to make the call? As mentioned in my post, the issue is with an error that I am getting in this specific instance. I have used SOAP APIs with GAS plenty of times without issue, and I've done the same thing as usual here.

Comment: Right... if you try to add the SOAPAction onto the header? Like ‘SOAPAction’:  ‘https://...’

Comment: Trying to remember all the issues I faced with SOAP and GAS...

Comment: Haha thanks, appreciate it! Still getting the same error, I'm afraid.